# BigQuery - Converting string to numeric

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, re2

I am looking for a regular expression syntax accepted by **RE2**,
to convert the following strings to numeric:

"339,840" -> 339840

"$100,000" -> 100000

"0.75" -> 0.75

"1" -> 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use `cast(regexp_replace(val, r'[^\d.]', '') as numeric)`

See below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select "339,840" val union all
  select "$100,000" union all
  select "0.75" union all
  select "1" 
)
select cast(regexp_replace(val, r'[^\d.]', '') as numeric)
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Very elegant, Thank you!